# Aggregate function turns special characters (e.g. aͤ) into sequence of brackets and characters

Tags: r, aggregate

I've got a big dataframe with two rows: the magazine issue and the text. I've tried to aggregate all rows that belong to the same magazine issue into one row. After I've done that though, words like *stuͤck* turned into *stu, <, u, +, >, ck*.
How do I keep the original letters?

```
Text <- c("laßt sie uns genien seyen vorwaͤrts strebe", "ersten bandes, ersten 
stuͤck verstaͤndigen ,jn" ,"Dreyein'ger Kraͤfte Wechselspiel: die Frucht")
issue <- c(1,1,2)
all <- data.frame(issue, Text)  
allagg <- aggregate(all["Text"], by=list(all$issue), c)
print(allagg)
```

I tried using `reprex` but this already transformed the special characters into quotation marks from the beginning, so I hope this example is enough.

Comment: That's just how unicode characters print in a data.frame. See `data.frame(a="\U364")` vs `"\U364"` - depending on the encoding of your host system, they might show differently.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get

```
> aggregate(all["Text"], by=list(all$issue), c)
  Group.1 Text
1       1 3, 2
2       2    1
```

I'm not sure why this differs from the behavior you were observing.

If I replace `FUN = c` with `FUN = paste`, I get the original characters:

```
> aggregate(all["Text"], by=list(all$issue), paste)
  Group.1
1       1
2       2
                                                                                       Text
1 laßt sie uns genien seyen vorwaͤrts strebe, ersten bandes, ersten \nstuͤck verstaͤndigen ,jn
2                                               Dreyein'ger Kraͤfte Wechselspiel: die Frucht
```